# UIButton UIWebView error

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton

Under the UIWebView didFailWithError, I create a UIButton and add it to the view:

```
 UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 ...
 ....
 [self.imageView addSubview:refreshButton];
```

When the button is clicked I request the webView reload a given URL.

What happens to the UIButton after this `didFailWithError` methods finished, is it automatically released.

Would I then be right in saying the UIButton has to be recreated again from scratch if the didFailWithError was caught again after the reload.

Also how would I remove the UIButton from my view in the webViewDidFinishLoad

```
[refreshButton removefromsuperview]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the UIButton after this didFailWithError methods finished, is it automatically released.

The button stays there if you do not remove it or the button's superview...

> Would I then be right in saying the UIButton has to be recreated again from scratch if the reload fails once more.

actually, this would only be necessary if your `self.imageView` gets unloaded or you remove it or the button explicitly...

> Also how would I remove the UIButton from my view in the webViewDidFinishLoad
>
> ```
>         [refreshButton removefromsuperview]
> ```

This is correct, but you should have `refreshButton` defined as a property in your class (otherwise it would be a local variable in `didFailWithError` and you could not refer it from other methods).

Possibly, since the button will trigger a reload, you would also like to remove it in `webViewDidStartLoad:`.

Comment: the button **does** get recreated in your code, be cause each time you enter `didFailWithError` a new one is created. This is correct, but you have to remove it also for things to work well and not have memory leaks.